# How to test iphone phonegap app on device without mac and xcode?

Tags: iphone, testing, cordova

I build a phonegap app and want to test it on my iphone without jailbreak it.
I use windows and do not own a mac.

I have an apple developer account.

Is it possible to test my app without jailbreak, xcode and mac?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap Developer app (http://app.phonegap.com)

It's not perfect (some of the plugins are a little out-of-date), you can only use core plugins, etc., but it does work.

If you need custom plugins or plugins not included in the distribution (or newer versions of those plugins), you're sadly out of luck, I think. If you're feeling adventurous, google for "iOS toolchain Windows" (Or Linux). You /might/ get lucky, but there's not going to be any real support for it.

Answer (score 0):

if it's just phonegap app, Try using ripples phonegap emulator [PhoneGap emulator](http://emulate.phonegap.com)

Else copy all the static HTML & JS files and load them in your phone. Open the index file in the mobile browser.

Comment: I want to test it on real device not on a emulator.

Comment: If I copy html, js, css files and start index it is a web app and not a phonegap app.